# matplotlib: не работает clf()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

В этом коде не работает clf(). Как это исправить?

```
    import numpy as np;
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import time
    plt.ion()
    #fig, ax=plt.subplots()
    l=np.sqrt(2.); l1=.2*l; l2=l-l1; e=.01; n1=10; n2=400; n=n1+n2
    h1=l1/n1; h2=l2/n2; J=2500; j1=50; tau=.5*h1*h1
    x=np.zeros(n+1,'float'); y =np.zeros(n+1,'float'); y1=np.zeros(n+1,'float'); u=np.zeros(n+1,'float')
    u1=np.zeros(n+1,'float'); uk=np.zeros((n+1,J+1),'float'); uk1=np.zeros((n+1,j1+1),'float')
    for i in range(0,n+1):
        if i<n1+1: x[i]=i*h1; 
        else: x[i]=x[i-1]+h2
        u[i]=0.; uk[i,0]=u[i]
    u[0]=1.; uk[0,0]=1.; uk1[0,0]=1.
    for j in range(1,J+1):
        for i in range(0,n+1): y[i]=u[i]
        for i in range(1,n): u[i]=.5*(y[i+1]+y[i-1]) 
        for i in range(0,n+1): u1[i]=u[i]; uk[i,j]=u[i]
    
    for j in range(1,j1+1):
        for i in range(0,n+1): uk1[i,j]=uk[i,j*50]
        plt.clf()
        plt.plot(x,uk1)
        plt.draw()
        plt.gcf().canvas.flush_events();plt.savefig('2/tmp_000%03d.png' %-j, dpi=100)
        time.sleep(0.02)
    plt.ioff()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: В чём выражается это "не работает"? Пишите подробнее.

Comment: pltclf() не стирает все рисунки накладывается

Comment: по идее plt.clf() должно стирать предыдущее изображение то есть должно получаться анимация ан нет все рисунки накладываются

Comment: Да вроде анимация другими способами делается в matplotlib

Comment: вроде бы этот способ должен работать вопрос в том почему? Если бы plt.clf() делал свое дело то должно же получиться. В чем дело?